# Android Null Pointer

Tags: android

What's going on here exactly? Trying to locate the null but unable to thus far.... I'm sure it's something silly

```
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.adamwhiles.tw33tz.appliaction.Tw33tzApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adamwhiles.tw33tz.appliaction.Tw33tzApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.adamwhiles.tw33tz-2.apk]
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:466)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3260)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.adamwhiles.tw33tz.appliaction.Tw33tzApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.adamwhiles.tw33tz-2.apk]
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:461)
04-29 06:04:03.845: E/AndroidRuntime(392):  ... 11 more
```

Here is the application class for my application....

```
package com.adamwhiles.tw33tz.application;

import oauth.signpost.OAuthProvider;
import oauth.signpost.commonshttp.CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import android.app.Application;

public class Tw33tzApplication extends Application {

    private Twitter twitter;

    /** @return the twitter */
    public Twitter getTwitter() {
        return twitter;
    }

    /** @param twitter
     *            the twitter to set */
    public void setTwitter(Twitter twitter) {
        this.twitter = twitter;
    }

    private OAuthProvider provider;
    private CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer;

    /** @param provider
     *            the provider to set */
    public void setProvider(OAuthProvider provider) {
        this.provider = provider;
    }

    /** @return the provider */
    public OAuthProvider getProvider() {
        return provider;
    }

    /** @param consumer
     *            the consumer to set */
    public void setConsumer(CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer consumer) {
        this.consumer = consumer;
    }

    /** @return the consumer */
    public CommonsHttpOAuthConsumer getConsumer() {
        return consumer;
    }
}
```

Here is the manifest for my application :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.adamwhiles.tw33tz"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
      <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
      <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> 

    <application android:label="Tw33tz" android:name=".appliaction.Tw33tzApplication">
        <activity android:name=".AuthActivity" android:label="Tw33tz">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="callback" android:host="tw33tz" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Tw33tzActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

hope this helps....

Comment: Did you override the application class?

Comment: Please post the application class name and the android manifest XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't find a class it's been lead to believe it should be able to.  I suspect you did not spell things consistently in both manifest and code:

The unfound class com.adamwhiles.tw33tz.**appliaction**.Tw33tzApplication

comes from the manifest

```
android:name=".appliaction.Tw33tzApplication"
```

vs the source provides

```
package com.adamwhiles.tw33tz.application;
```